# Checking for undefined in if statements, leading to uncaught errors because item in if is undefined. What to do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas, oboe.js

I see there are not many oboe tags used on SO, but please help if you can, this is more of a general javascript question about handing uncaught errors for undefined. Thanks!~

I am using Oboe.js to stream data to webpage from a MongoDB atlas collection. In the MongoDB JSON, some of the _ids have a path of `item.image.filename` which is a path to an image. Some do not have item.image.filename, as not all of the streamed items need an image. The loading stops when there is an undefined value and I see an error in the console.

I would expect that if there is not a value present that oboe would just carry on to the next record as its default behavior. However, the _ids without the image path are throwing an exception in the if statement I am using to rule them out. I want to be clear that item.image.filename is not there with no value in it or set to null, it just doesn't exist. From what little I know of MongoDB, the flexibility to have each item be unique is one of its big advantages.

I believe I have hit on all manners of checking for this with if statements, even using a try catch block, but when compiled, the if statement itself is throwing this error: `oboe-browser.min.js:5 Uncaught Error: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined at oboe-browser.min.js:5` . The if else block would render html without the image if undefined, otherwise render it.

One way to fix this would be to add a `item.image.filename` to each record, but I would rather not, there are a lot of records, that's my last resort. Seems there is a better wait to sort this out.

Here is what I have tried:

`if(!item.image.filename)`

`if(item.image.filename === undefined)`

`if(item.image.filename == 'undefined')`

`if(item.image.filename == undefined)`

`if(item.image.filename === 'undefined')`

`if(item.image.filename === null)`

`if(item.image.filename == null)`

I took an alternative route like `if(item.image.filename !== undefined)` both with and without quotes, and with null too.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What does the data look like?

Comment: you can try if(item.image && item.image.filename) return or if(item.image.filename in json) return

Comment: Could you add what your oboe call looks like? I suspect that would make it easier to debug 

Comment: Hey all, I figured it out. I had to look at whether item.image was undefined, not item.image.filename. Once I changed that, I was in good shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `typeof`:

```js
if(typeof item !== 'object' || typeof item.image !== 'object' || item.image.filename === undefined){
  console.log("undefined as far as you're concerned");
}
```

What you need to know is you cannot do a `=== undefined` test on a variable that has not been declared. But it is okay to do that test on an Object property that doesn't exist, as long as the Object does exist.

Comment: Your posting of ``item.image`` and not ``item.image.filename`` led to the solution. The code would only work if checking for undefined of the former, but not the later. So I ended up using a ternary like this in my code. I was really going down a rathole. Thanks.

```
${item.image ? `<img class="card-img-top thumbnail" src="/images/` + item.image.filename + `" alt=""></img>` : ``}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
if(item.image.filename in this)
```

or

```
if(!(item.image.filename in this))
```

where this is an object or array

Comment: I wish I understood "this" better in JS, but I was led to the solution by the StackSlave. I ended up needing to use a ternary, much cleaner in the end.

Comment: yeah his solution is better but if you want I can explain 'this' to you and what it's uses are just tag me here